# Make Page Jump to Anchor on Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Greetings I'm working on a gallery script and would like to have it so when the page is loaded it is automatically positioned to the top of an anchor I have set.  I've tried this code:

```
<script>location.href = "#trendnav";</script>


<a name="trendnav"></a>
```

And it doesn't seem to do anything.  The more instantaneous this seems to the user, the better.

Comment: Use `location.hash = "#trendav";`

Comment: Use `<a id="trendav"></a>` and as Ian pointed `location.hash = '#trendav`

Comment: @jon:please accept the answer if you think its worthy..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  window.location.hash = "#VALUE";
```

[***Fiddle Demo 1***](http://jsfiddle.net/dxNKG/2/)

[***Fiddle Demo 2***](http://jsfiddle.net/dxNKG/3/)

or

[***window.scrollTo***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Or, using your original approach:

```
$('span#godown').click(function(){location='#anchor';});
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/dxNKG/1/
. I assigned a clickable span with the task of being the button that triggers it.

Actually, your original syntax `location.href='#anchor'` is correct, but you should fire it only *after* the DOM has loaded completely. So, either put the `<script>` section at the end of your page or do something like

```
window.onload=function(){window.location.href='#anchor';};
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/bUaTT/  (without jQuery) 
or, since you are using jQuery:

```
$(function(){window.location.href='#anchor';})
```